# Steam Error loading Fallout: New Vegas

Tags: steam, fallout-new-vegas

Today I launched Fallout: New Vegas and it gave me an error:

```
Application load error P:**********
```

(Dashes are hidden since it might be a security thing)

I was busy at Vault 11 fighting laggy robots at 1 FPS in the sacrificial chamber and I had to end task the game after saving it because i was getting tired and it was so laggy that the quit button wouldn't work.

I also ended Steam's Task while the game was Syncing.

What should I do to get the game working again? Buy it again? ._.

**EDIT:** Steam launched the game with Error code 80. What's that?

Comment: The load error isn't a security thing, just the load error code. Could be useful to know what it is!

Comment: Yeah, seems the way to go should be verify cache.  Googling the error message next time should help you faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thing to try would be to verify the integrity of the Steam Cache.

To do this

1. find the game in your Steam library
2. right click and select **properties**
3. click **Local Files**
4. click **Verify Local Cache**

see if that helps

Comment: Nope. Still gave me an error whenever i launch it through steam or if i launch it through NVSE.

Comment: @MarkieJonesWTF so it verified and didn't download any additional files? Have you restarted steam mand/or your pc?

Comment: Just restarted steam after verifying game cache. Thanks!

Comment: Good good! Glad it's back up and running!